# "get your controllers out of your views and then get your models out of your controllers"

Tags: php, mysql

So today a friend is helping me with a PHP project I am making. He looked over my code and told me a few things to fix, etc. There was one thing he said which I don't quite understand. He said "get your controllers out of your views and then get your models out of your controllers". For instance he pointed out this code here which is in my website memberlist page:

```
$get_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_users)) {
    $username = ucfirst($row['username']);
    $user_group = getUserGroup($row['userlevel']);
    $dor = $row['dor'];

    print("<tr>
               <td class='border-bottom'>$username</td>
           <td class='border-bottom'>$user_group</td>
           <td class='border-bottom'>$dor</td>
          </tr>");
}
```

Could someone possibly explain what they mean't about that? Could you also provide some resources if there are any.

Comment: He's talking about MVC...   You can totally ignore that comment if you do not care to develop MVC.  Don't let anyone tell you their 'one way' is the right way.

Comment: That said, it's generally accepted that your existing code is a far cry from best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's referring to what's called MVC, or Model View Controller.

The Controller class handles the request, the Model handles calculation and compuation (usually, database connections and communication), and then it (the Controller) loads a View with the info gathered in the Model, and display that to the user.

What he means is that you should separate your logic from your display.

---

MVC is a great design pattern for larger applications. But if your application doesn't have many pages, and/or is small, you don't need it.

Comment: So at that point where it loads all the members, would I have a class called.. Let's say dbhandler, then I would call it $db=new dbhandler(); and the make a function that loads and returns all the members? $db->loadMembers();

Comment: I suggest you read and feel PHP frameworks that are MVC based. I recommend CodeIgniter. Their documentation is very thorough and easy to understand.

Comment: You would have a class called Users, which is your model and you would have a function called getUsers in there. So `$users->getUsers()`. The `db` class would be separate and is used more as a library which deals with the db connection and running sql queries and returning results.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with "models out of controllers".  Somebody's gotta map requests to model objects.  Be careful that your friend isn't one of the zealots who creates parallel object hierarchies for the sole purpose of maintaining layer purity.    Layering is good; dogma is not.

Comment: Can you please clarify a little bit about what you mean by "map requests to model objects" and how it goes against the idea of keeping model code such as data access, calculations, etc.. out of the controller, who's sole purpose is to be the 'glue' between the view and the model?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

Controller file:

```
$users_info = get_user_details();
show_users_info($users_info);
```

Model file:

```
function get_user_details(){
    //... interacting with database
    return $details; // an associative array for username, usergroup, dor
}
```

View file:

```
function show_users_info($data){
    for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
        //your <table>, <tr>, <td> html here
    }
}
```

You can see that model file is responsible for preparing the data.
and the view file is responsible for displaying the data - you can use template engine such as Smarty or Dwoo to help with that.
And, there are many PHP MVC framework available for you to learn it, e.g. [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com)

The idea is to separate the things. The logic of preparing the data does not interfere with how the data is displayed as html. You can modify any one of them without affecting each other - you will need to care less about the other stuff when you modify one stuff.

Answer (score -2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Giving link only answers is discouraged. Please explain your answer in your own words.

Comment: This is hardly an answer. You're just giving a link to an article someone else wrote. You should include something as simple as: Your friend was referring to the idea of MVC, it's a way to separate your code into "logical" sections which are responsible for specific actions. You can read more at ... etc...

Comment: Giving the wrong link to the answer maybe. Giving the right link to explain the answer which is contributed by people all over the world is not 'haaardly an answer.'

Comment: @battlemidget - Actually, giving a wrong link is just a wrong answer. The problem is that your answer accomplished absolutely nothing other than provide another few hits to Wikipedia. That's why your answer is hardly an answer, not because the link is wrong but because you gave no explanation for the link or how it relates to the original question. You're welcome to argue me on this point but I would suggest that you just delete this answer voluntarily and save yourself some rep from further downvotes.

Comment: I can tell youre upset. I tell you what, I'll write every little thing down next time so you can follow along with the rest of the group.